# if I use https, can someone (who monitors my wifi) see what I am doing?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, tor

I use a public wifi.

I wonder if someone would be able to see what I am doing over the internet when I use https. And for plain http? What could I do to be safer? Using tor? But what about the other programs such as Skype, Dropbox, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: From what I know, with https it's not possible to see what you send, but it's still possible to see where it's sent. It's like a sealed envelope really. Can't open it, but you can still read the address. I'm not sure Tor would work in that case because the middleman would be between you and the first node.

Comment: Applications like Dropbox and Skype rarely would send plain text data, they usually develop their cryptography or use SSL too.

Comment: Actually a surprising number of services still use no cryptography at all, except for session login. TOR or a VPN service are the most secure route, in that they obscure both your destination and your content, regardless of whether upper layer cryptography like SSL is in play.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Is visiting HTTPS websites on a public hotspot secure?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/is-visiting-https-websites-on-a-public-hotspot-secure), which coincidentally was migrated from here.

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS uses SSL/TLS to encrypt data sent between you and the server, so the http requests you send, and the responses you receive will be hidden from others.

On the other hand, it is still possible for eavesdroppers to see *which* servers you are connecting to.

TOR can prevent eavesdroppers from telling which sites you are connecting to, but the exit node *can* view your traffic (though it doesn't know where it is coming from). So even if you use TOR you will still want to use HTTPS as well.

DropBox and Skype should both be encrypting your data in transit. Microsoft and Dropbox themselves, however, can still access your data.

Comment: Be careful not to get to overconfident if you use TOR. TOR can be tricky to configure correctly, and it's possible that some traffic may   end up going over your regular connection. You can try using a tool like WireShark to check if this is the case.

Comment: I also caution use against TOR without knowing how it works, and how to protect yourself, TOR didn't protect the identity of the student who called in a bomb threat.  ( don't get me wrong the student deserves everything that comes from doing that ).  It should be point out ANY HTTPS website can see the data it sends to you.  It has to be able to.

Comment: the most effective way to run TOR, is from a live CD pre-configured to use it, or via a hardware proxy like Safeplug https://pogoplug.com/safeplug